# How does getProperty work in SpiderMonkey?

Tags: firefox, spidermonkey

I'm looking at source code of SpiderMonkey and trying to understand how to customize the function 'getProperty'. But it's hard to track to the proper place that 'getProperty' really set the property to return value. So anyone can show the 'proper place' in code?

Currently, I'm at NativeObject.h that:

```
inline bool
js::GetProperty(JSContext* cx, HandleObject obj, HandleObject receiver, HandleId id, MutableHandleValue vp)
{
    if (GetPropertyOp op = obj->getOps()->getProperty)
        return op(cx, obj, receiver, id, vp);
    return NativeGetProperty(cx, obj.as<NativeObject>(), receiver, id, vp);
}
```

What will op(cx, obj, receiver, id, vp) do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can provide an object with custom behavior to the script by implementing [`JSClass`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_reference/JSClass) (out of date documentation warning). Or these days it might be easier to do it from JS land with a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

What code is responsible for returning the property depends on the kind of object and the property. I'm really not sure why you're looking at NativeObject. [jsobj.h](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/js/src/jsobj.h#820) is a more common implementation.

You might also want to ask in IRC or one of the [other channels listed at the SpiderMonkey MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey#Join_the_SpiderMonkey_community).